# Pagination For Search Results using Yii

Tags: php, search, yii, pagination

I have a search form, which returns a bunch of images. Because their number can be high, I would prefer having the results displayed using pagination. However, I cannot seem to get it to work properly. I have moved everything to the view to keep things as simple as possible.

Here is my code snippet for the search and pagination:

```
$searchData = $model->search(); // this is the result of the search
$pages = new CPagination($searchData->itemCount); 
$searchData->setPagination($pages); 
$pages->applyLimit($searchData->criteria); 
$pages->pageSize = 2;
```

Then, I display the results using a "foreach" statement:

```
foreach($searchData->getData() as $data)
{
// results displayed here
}
```

Finally, I have the CLinkPager widget:

```
 $this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
    'pages' => $pages,
    'header' => 'Отиди на страница: ',
    'nextPageLabel' => 'Следваща',
    'prevPageLabel' => 'Предишна',
                     )); `
```

The problem is: there is not a relation between the widget and the displayed results. 
For instance, if I get 4 results, the widget correctly shows that there are 2 pages. However, the results are not displayed in two pages, all are shown in one and clicking the CLinkPager links does nothing.

I have done pagination in the past successfully before, but for all the data using 
    model()->findAll().

How do I state the relation between the pagination widget and the search results... ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [take a lokk at this site](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25901-pagination-solution-simple-and-complex-ways/)

Comment: It was not exactly what I was looking for, but I got some inspiration from the link and managed to solve my problem. Thank you, sincerely!

The trick was to get the query criteria from $model->search() and then use $model->findAll() with that criteria.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are possibly overcomplicating the process. You could more easily use CListView widget to display your results with pagination.

Your controller may have this;

```
public function actionIndex(){
    $model = new Model;
    $this->render('index', array('model' => $model);
}
```

Your model needs to have a search method that returns an instance of CActiveDataProvider, for example

```
public function search() {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->compare('id', $this->id, true);
        $criteria->compare('title', $this->title, true);
        $criteria->order = 'sortOrder';
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
    }
```

Then in your view file you can use this code;

```
$this->widget('widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'itemView' => '_list',
    'template' => '{pager}{items}',
    'pager' => array(
        'nextPageLabel' => 'Следваща',
        'prevPageLabel' => 'Предишна',
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the CListView by putting this in your extensions folder, and change the page size there.

```
<?php
Yii::import('zii.widgets.CListView');

class CustomListView extends CListView {
    public function init() {
        if ($this->dataProvider !== null)
            $this->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 30;

        $this->dataProvider->pagination->nextPageLabel => 'Следваща';
        $this->dataProvider->pagination->prevPageLabel => 'Предишна';
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

Then, use the CustomListView as follows:

```
<?php $this->widget('CustomListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```

You do not need to use `CLinkPager` widget directly this way.